# Token generation through PowerBI client sending an "Unauthorized" error

Tags: azure, powerbi

I am in process of embedding PowerBI into custom website. It seems that most of the things is working fine, but last thing creating a problem. it shows an error “Unauthorized”. I hope, you can help here.

Following are things working ok and one last thing is not working.

- Able to generate access token against AAD.
- Able to communicate with PowerBI.
- Able to Get report from PowerBI.
- When I try to generate token through PowerBI client, it is generating an “unauthorized” error.

Below is a snippet of the code in ** which is troubling.

```js
public async Task < EmbedConfig > GetEmbedConfigAsync()
{
  var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(await 
       _authTokenService.GetAccessTokenAsync(), "Bearer");
      using var pbiClient = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(_configuration["PowerBi:ApiUrl"]),
    tokenCredentials);
  var id = _configuration["PowerBi:WorkspaceId"];

  var report = await pbiClient.Reports.GetReportInGroupAsync(
    Guid.Parse(_configuration["PowerBi:WorkspaceId"]),
    Guid.Parse(_configuration["PowerBi:ReportId"])
  );

  var tokenRequest = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "view");
  // **
  var embedToken = await pbiClient.Reports.GenerateTokenAsync(
    Guid.Parse(_configuration["PowerBi:WorkspaceId"]),
    Guid.Parse(_configuration["PowerBi:ReportId"]),
    tokenRequest
  );
  // **

  return new EmbedConfig
  {
    EmbedUrl = report.EmbedUrl,
      EmbedToken = embedToken.Token,
      Id = report.Id.ToString()
  };
}
```

Below is the exception, I am getting.

```
Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'
         at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.ReportsOperations.GenerateTokenInGroupWithHttpMessagesAsync(Guid groupId, Guid reportId, GenerateTokenRequest requestParameters, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.ReportsOperationsExtensions.GenerateTokenAsync(IReportsOperations operations, Guid groupId, Guid reportId, GenerateTokenRequest requestParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at WebApplication1.PowerBiService.GetEmbedConfigAsync() in C:\Users\ABU177\source\repos\Project\WebApplication1\PowerBiService.cs:line 41
         at WebApplication1.Controllers.PowerBiController.GetEmbedInfo() in C:\Users\ABU177\source\repos\Project\WebApplication1\Controllers\PowerBiController.cs:line 19
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Check if this helps https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Developer/C-Power-BI-API-401-Unauthorized/m-p/1139779